# gsoap Server does not accept Client request

Tags: gsoap

I have created a web service in gsoap, but server does not accept requests. There is no error, but i dont understand why it does not accept requests from client. I am pasting my client and server code here.
    Clientcode

```
EnrollmentServiceSOAPProxy proxy;
_ns1__performRequest *req = new _ns1__performRequest();
_ns1__performRequestResponse *res = new _ns1__performRequestResponse(); 
if(proxy.performRequest(req, res) == SOAP_OK)
   print "OK" // pseudo code for print. 
else
    print "Not Ok"
```

Server Code:

```
int __ns1__performRequest(soap *, _ns1__performRequest *ns1__performRequest, _ns1__performRequestResponse *ns1__performRequestResponse)
{
    ns1__performRequestResponse->jobID = "1011";
    return SOAP_OK;
}
```

The server is listening on localhost. but the request does not reach the server.

This is the WSDL file:https://www.dropbox.com/s/n2sdv51qmttp7vb/EnrollmentService.wsdl

I debugged the code, but it did not help me.

Comment: Can you share the part of your server code where you make a soap_begin_serve() call and dispatch() on the service object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happend with me before. In service definition i used different port, while the server was listening to different port. This seems your problem too.

Answer (score 0):

The service endpoint may not be set to your server, but to whatever the WSDL defines as the server address. You should use `EnrollmentServiceSOAPProxy proxy("URL");` with the URL that is your server's endpoint address (`http://hostaddr` or `http://localhost:8000` when you run your server local on port 8000).